# Nested Parameter substitution problems in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create a jmx to test some database entries. The exact queries are not known beforehand and need to be picked from one of many sets of queries, that I have declared in separate pre-processor units.

For eg. one of the set of queries is:

```
String[][] animals = new String[][]{
{"VLS_CATS_ASSOC","CAT_ID_AS = '${CAT_ID_AS}'"},
{"VLS_DOGS_EXCH","DOG_ID_ST = '${DOG_ID_ST}' and DOG_TXT_REF = '${DOG_TXT_REF}'"},
};
```

The 2D array has two entries, the 'table name' and the 'where clause'
So, the jdbc request is `select * from ${table_name} where ${where_clause}`
I've set up a loop controller for iterating through the tables one by one, and as a child i have jdbc sampler, that has the csv table config which will contain data for `CAT_ID_AS, DOG_ID_ST, DOG_TXT_REF`.

Currently, when i see my requests through a results listener, i see that the queries sent are:
`select * from VLS_CATS_ASSOC where DOG_ID_ST = '${DOG_ID_ST}' and DOG_TXT_REF = '${DOG_TXT_REF}'`

It is clear from the output that the first level of substitution has worked, but not the second one.

Can anybody please help me on this?

Edit: Adding an image of the test plan. [Jmeter Test Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08SiJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `${CAT_ID_AS}` notation in (I presume) the BeanShell strings: while it is generally working, that's an undocumented and error-prone feature.

The legit way is `vars.get("CAT_ID_AS")`

`vars` is a pre-defined object available in any BeanShell piece inside your test plan

So your code would be looking like

`String[][] animals = new String[][]{ {"VLS_CATS_ASSOC","CAT_ID_AS = '" + vars.get("CAT_ID_AS") + "'"},` ... etc

Comment: I've tried that, but it substitutes the values as null.
select * from VLS_CATS_ASSOC where DOG_ID_ST = 'null' and DOG_TXT_REF = 'null'

Comment: Then it is obvious that vars aren't set. Show your plan, show how you call it.

Comment: Added the test plan. By the way, i had log statements in a pre-processor element (which is a child of the the JDBC Request) where I can see that the data is getting fetched. It just fails during the substitution part.

Comment: The plan at high level is not helpful. Show how you set the vars & how you then refer them. Meanwhile, you can use a Debug Sampler placed right after the pre-processors that are setting the variable values - then you'd be able to see the state of your vars in the Result Tree listener.